# KeyError whilelooking for locals names

Tags: python, list-comprehension, local-variables

I tried to get a List of the names of local Variables with List Comprehension:

```
local_names = [locals()[name] for name in locals().keys()]
```

and get a KeyError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\kurse\python\html\resources\python\ch21\verfuegbar.py", line 59, in <module>
    local_names = [locals()[name] for name in locals().keys()]
  File "C:\kurse\python\html\resources\python\ch21\verfuegbar.py", line 59, in <listcomp>
    local_names = [locals()[name] for name in locals().keys()]
KeyError: '__name__'
```

If I do about the same in a loop, there is no Problem:

```
name = None # to get 'name' into the dict before loop
for name in locals() :
    print(f"Name: {name} ==>> {locals()[name]}")
```

Can anybody explain it to me?
Thanks!!!

Comment: The left-most locals happens in a different scope from the file level because it is executing the list comprehension. Try printing [locals() for _ in range(1)]

Comment: Also, you want to work with the keys and values at the same time, I would use items() rather than keys().

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you go, there you are. If you say "here" and then walk into another room, it's different. Similarly, if you call locals(), then change the scope and call it again, it will be different.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals

> Update and return a dictionary representing the current local symbol table. Free variables are returned by locals() when it is called in function blocks, but not in class blocks. Note that at the module level, locals() and globals() are the same dictionary.

```
# what you think locals is
print(locals().keys())

# what it looks like inside another scope
scope_names = [locals().keys() for _ in range(1)]
print(scope_names[0])
```

> dict_keys(['**name**', '**doc**', '**package**', '**loader**', '**spec**', '**builtins**', '**file**'])
> dict_keys(['.0', '_'])

You could always work with my_local_variables = locals(), and then work with it from a different scope:

Comment: this is a real good answer!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm afraid, simple snapshot = locals wouldn't do it, because 'snapshot' ist just another reference to the same 'thing'. I think I need a copy of locals: e.g. snapshot = dict(locals()). Would you agree?

Comment: That is an improvement for the concept of a "snapshot" in general, yes, but the problem was locals() referencing a completely different dict in different parts of your code. I'll change the name, since it's not a snapshot. Thanks. (also might need deepcopy)

Comment: ok! and Thanks a lot!

Comment: (also, you can "accept" the answer, if it's useful and complete)

Comment: as you can see, I'm a new here, how can I accept an answere?